# Eclipse CDT: how to test functions?

Tags: c++, eclipse, function, testing

How can I test the functions I write before using them in my main C++ application?

Say I have a main.cpp that uses function foo() declared in mylib.h and defined in mylib.cpp.
I would like to test foo() extensively on "toy" situations, to check that it behaves as expected.

How can I do this in Eclipse? For my need it would be enough to have a test.cpp so that I can test single functions at the occurrence. I just would do this adding a "test" option to my makefile that compiles "test.cpp" rather than "main.cpp" but I don't know how to do this in Eclipse.

Any other less naive advice is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should have two projects :

1. project with your main, that uses the library
2. project where you implement your library, with the unit test main. This main needs to initialize the unit test framework, and execute tests

So, if you haven't, pick [an unit testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B), and add tests.

Comment: but having two projects doesn't mean that I have to recompile the two projects separately every time?

Comment: @LucaCerone Yes, they are independent. First build and execute unit tests to make sure they pass. Then build your application, and do other kinds of tests (integration, functional, etc)

Comment: @LucaCerone You can mark projects in eclipse dependent on others, so build actions on one project will trigger the same build actions on the projects it depends on.